# Function that can call two APIs, one of them returns an array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have the following code:

```
getElements(apiUrl: string): Observable<Element[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(apiUrl + 'test/elements').pipe(
        catchError(error => {
            if(error.status === StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND){
                console.warn(error.status + ': no data found');
            }
            else {
                this.openModalError(error);
            }
            return throwError(() => error);
        })
    );
}
```

Depending on `apiUrl`, API will return either `Element` or `Element[]`. But I want my function to always return an array. How can I convert `Element` to an array when it isn't?

Comment: A starting point would be telling the compiler "API will return either `Element` or `Element[]`", rather than that it could return `any`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only use rxjs/operator [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) to return if it's an array return the value, else create an array with an unique element. To know it we use the function [isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
return this.httpClient.get<Element[]>(apiUrl + 'test/elements').pipe(
     map((res:any)=>Array.isArray(res)?res:[res]),
     catchError...
})
```